# Rshiny download timeVis timeline as image

Tags: r, shiny

I am trying to figure out how to download a timeVis timeline from my shiny app.  More specifically, I want to save the version that *the user has modified.*

What I mean is, once the timeline is generated and displayed, the user can interact and drag the block elements around to arrange them how they want. I then want a button that saves an image of the timeline in it's current state. (Ultimately I will be including this image in a zip file of items that get downloaded together.)

I tried to implement an answer that I found on another thread, but I'm not sure if it's the correct modern way of doing it, plus it doesn't work.

Ideas?

**CODE**

```
if (interactive()) {
  library(shiny)
  library(timevis)
  library(lubridate)
  
  starthour <- 8
  today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
  todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
  todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
  todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")
  
  items <- data.frame(
    category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
    group=c(1,2,3,4),
    className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
    content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
    length = c(480,60,120,90)
  )
  
  groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)
  
  data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                           start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                           end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
  )
  
  ui <- fluidPage(
    tags$head(
      tags$style(HTML("
                        .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                        .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                        .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                        .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                        "))),
    timevisOutput("appts"),
    div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
    div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
    tableOutput("table"),
    downloadButton("downloadData", "Download timeline",class = "btn-success")
  )
  
  server <- function(input, output) {
    output$appts <- renderTimevis(
      timevis(
        data = data,
        groups = groups,
        fit = TRUE,
        options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,start = todayAM,
                       end = todayPM,showCurrentTime = FALSE,showMajorLabels=FALSE)
        
      )
    )
    
    output$selected <- renderText(
      paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
    )
    
    output$window <- renderText(
      paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
    )
    
    output$table <- renderTable(
      input$appts_data
    )
    time_line <- reactive(appts)
    
    output$downloadData <- downloadHandler( 
      filename = function(){ paste("Timeline", Sys.Date(), '.png', sep = '') }, 
      content = function(file){ time_line %>% htmltools::html_print() %>% webshot::webshot(file = filename) } )
    
    
  }
  shinyApp(ui, server)
 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using the JavaScript library **dom-to-image**:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

starthour <- 8
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
  group=c(1,2,3,4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
  length = c(480,60,120,90)
)

groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)

data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                         start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                         end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#download').on('click', function(){
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('appts'), {bgcolor: 'white'})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'my-timeline.png';
        link.href = dataUrl;
        link.click();
    });
  });
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                    .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                    "))),
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
  div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
  tableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("download", "Download timeline", class = "btn-success")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data = data,
      groups = groups,
      fit = TRUE,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,start = todayAM,
                     end = todayPM,showCurrentTime = FALSE,showMajorLabels=FALSE)
    )
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
  )
  
  output$window <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
  )
  
  output$table <- renderTable(
    input$appts_data
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Now I have to see if I can integrate this with a .zip download.  I want to save the datatable as a csv, and package it with the .PNG file in a .zip archive.

Comment: @Steve Doable with some JavaScript libraries. Open a new question and I will answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783349/rshiny-download-button-that-gathers-multiple-files-from-various-locations

Comment: Is there a way to download as pdfs?