# Rshiny download button that gathers multiple files from various locations

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am looking for info on having a download button in my app that pulls various files into a zip archive.

My app displays a timeline and a datatable, and will have files associated with entries on the datatable. The files will be stored in a directory in the app, and I will have a column of filenames in the datatable.

The idea is that when I click the download button, a zip archive will be created that contains a couple of standard files that I point to, a csv of the datatable, a png of the timeline, and any files that I have associated with the selected entries of the datatable.

I haven't begun to deal with the files associated with the datatable, but that's my ultimate end state.

**Current Code**

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

starthour <- 8
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
  group=c(1,2,3,4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
  length = c(480,60,120,90)
)

groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)

data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                         start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                         end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#download').on('click', function(){
domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('appts'), {bgcolor: 'white'})
.then(function (dataUrl) {
var link = document.createElement('a');
link.download = 'my-timeline.png';
link.href = dataUrl;
link.click();
});
});
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "myJS.js"),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                    .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                    "))),
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
  div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
  tableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("download", "Download timeline", class = "btn-success")
    )

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data = data,
      groups = groups,
      fit = TRUE,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,start = todayAM,
                     end = todayPM,showCurrentTime = FALSE,showMajorLabels=FALSE)
    )
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
  )
  
  output$window <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
  )
  
  output$table <- renderTable(
    input$appts_data
  )
  
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT**

Here is how I am currently downloading selected rows from a datatble in my production app.

```
output$downloadData2 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {paste('Selected Retreat Options', Sys.Date(), '.csv', sep = '')},
      content = function(file){ write.csv(thedata()[input[["tbl1_rows_selected"]], ],file)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a way using the JavaScript libraries

- **dom-to-image** to export the timeline as a PNG image;
- **table2CSV** to convert the table to a CSV string;
- **JSZip** to zip.

---

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

starthour <- 8
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
  group=c(1,2,3,4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
  length = c(480,60,120,90)
)

groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)

data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                         start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                         end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
)

js <- "
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#download').on('click', function(){
    var csv = $('#table table').table2CSV({delivery:'value'});
    domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('appts'), {bgcolor: 'white'})
      .then(function (dataUrl) {
        var zip = new JSZip();
        var idx = dataUrl.indexOf('base64,') + 'base64,'.length; 
        var content = dataUrl.substring(idx);
        zip.file('timeline.png', content, {base64: true})
          .file('timeline.csv', btoa(csv), {base64: true});
        zip.generateAsync({type:'base64'}).then(function (b64) {
          var link = document.createElement('a');
          link.download = 'mytimeline.zip';
          link.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + b64;
          link.click();
        });
      });
  });
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/rubo77/table2CSV/table2CSV.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                    .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                    "))),
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
  div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
  tableOutput("table"),
  actionButton("download", "Download timeline", class = "btn-success")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data = data,
      groups = groups,
      fit = TRUE,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,start = todayAM,
                     end = todayPM,showCurrentTime = FALSE,showMajorLabels=FALSE)
    )
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
  )
  
  output$window <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
  )
  
  output$table <- renderTable(
    input$appts_data
  )
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

## EDIT

In order for the above solution to work, the table must be displayed in the page. Below is a solution which does not require that. It uses the JavaScript library **PapaParse**.

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)

starthour <- 8
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayzero <- paste(today,"00:00:00")
todayAM <- paste(today,"07:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room","IceBreaker","Activity","Break"),
  group=c(1,2,3,4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point","purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room","Introductions","Red Rover","Lunch"),
  length = c(480,60,120,90)
)

groups <- data.frame(id= items$group, content = items$category)

data <- items %>% mutate(id = 1:4,
                         start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
                         end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
)

js <- "
function downloadZIP(jsontable){
  var csv = Papa.unparse(jsontable);
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('appts'), {bgcolor: 'white'})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      var zip = new JSZip();
      var idx = dataUrl.indexOf('base64,') + 'base64,'.length; 
      var content = dataUrl.substring(idx);
      zip.file('timeline.png', content, {base64: true})
        .file('timeline.csv', btoa(csv), {base64: true});
      zip.generateAsync({type:'base64'}).then(function (b64) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'mytimeline.zip';
        link.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + b64;
        link.click();
      });
    });
}
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(){
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('download', downloadZIP);
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.2.0/papaparse.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(HTML("
                    .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
                    .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
                    .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
                    "))),
  timevisOutput("appts"),
  div("Selected items:", textOutput("selected", inline = TRUE)),
  div("Visible window:", textOutput("window", inline = TRUE)),
  actionButton("download", "Download timeline", class = "btn-success")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$appts <- renderTimevis(
    timevis(
      data = data,
      groups = groups,
      fit = TRUE,
      options = list(editable = TRUE, multiselect = TRUE, align = "center", stack = TRUE,start = todayAM,
                     end = todayPM,showCurrentTime = FALSE,showMajorLabels=FALSE)
    )
  )
  
  output$selected <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_selected, collapse = " ")
  )
  
  output$window <- renderText(
    paste(input$appts_window[1], "to", input$appts_window[2])
  )
  
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "download", 
      fromJSON(toJSON(input$appts_data), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: I'm really starting to think I should be doing this entire page in jquery.  Lol.  Thanks again!  I like how you are just getting around the Rshiny limitations with the JS.

Comment: Is there any way to download a table WITHOUT displaying it?  In my actual working app, the table is displayed, the user selects items and clicks a button to display the timeline. Then the packet is downloaded from there. I never actually display an additional table with the selected rows like in my generic app above.

Comment: Or maybe I can just hide the table, since I think it has to be generated for your script to work?

Comment: @Steve This works if you hide the table like this: `div(tableOutput("table"), style="visibility: hidden;")`. But this displays a white area. You can hide the table in such a way that there's no white area by doing `div(tableOutput("table"), style="display: none;")`, but then the CSV file is empty.  So use `visibility: hidden` and put the table at the bottom of the page.

Comment: Yea, I was just playing with that, as well as shinyjs to hide the table. Which also results in an empty csv.  I may just have to incorporate that table.   I added a block of code to my question that shows how I am currently downloading the selected rows from my datatable.

Comment: I might need to make a new generic version that has a better representation of my current functionality.

Comment: Awesome, I was able to incorporate that into a better representation of my app. I posted a new question with your functions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62797460/rshiny-pass-list-of-files-to-javascript-downloader

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I'm looking for a way to upload user data and map the column names and data values to pre-defined column names data values from a database and save the uploaded data to the database. The next time user uploads, it has to rember the previous mapping. Wondering if there is any R package for mapping or a demo shiny app that you are aware of which does this mapping on UI ?