# R/Rshiny adding item to list of factors

Tags: r, shiny

Why is this so difficult?! I have (what I believe is a factor vector) and I want to add an item to the list so I can use it farther down the road.

I want to add "memo.txt" to the factor vector filenames.

I have figured out how to add a factor level to the list, but not the item itself.

```
levels(filenames) <- c(levels(filenames), "memo.txt")
```

The specific section I am working in is here:

```
observeEvent(input$download, {
    filenames <- na.omit(data[input$tbl1_rows_selected, "file_name"])
    
#I need to add items to "filenames" here. I then display "test" to make sure those items exist in "filenames" - ie, i want to add "memo.txt" to filenames.

    output$test <- renderTable(filenames)
   
    files <- file.path(".", "www", filenames)
    URIs <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(i){
      URI <- dataURI(file = files[i])
      list(filename = filenames[i], uri = substr(URI, 14, nchar(URI)))
    })
    table <- fromJSON(toJSON(input$appts_data), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "download",
      list(table = table, URIs = URIs)
    )
  })
```

The entire code:

```
library(shiny)
library(timevis)
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(jsonlite)
library(base64enc)

starthour <- 8
today <- as.character(Sys.Date())
todayzero <- paste(today, "00:00:00")
todayAM <- paste(today, "07:00:00")
todayPM <- paste(today, "18:00:00")

items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room", "IceBreaker", "Activity", "Break"),
  group = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point", "purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room", "Introductions", "Red Rover", "Lunch"),
  length = c(480, 60, 120, 90),
  file_name = c("Toolkit_placeholder.pdf", NA, "Placeholder.txt", "Toolkit_placeholder.pdf")
)

groups <- data.frame(id = items$group, content = items$category)

data <- items %>% mutate(
  id = 1:4,
  start = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour),
  end   = as.POSIXct(todayzero) + hours(starthour) + minutes(items$length)
)

js <- "
function downloadZIP(x){
  var csv = Papa.unparse(x.table);
  var URIs = x.URIs;
  domtoimage.toPng(document.getElementById('appts'), {bgcolor: 'white'})
    .then(function (dataUrl) {
      var zip = new JSZip();
      var idx = dataUrl.indexOf('base64,') + 'base64,'.length;
      var content = dataUrl.substring(idx);
      zip.file('timeline.png', content, {base64: true})
       .file('timeline.csv', btoa(csv), {base64: true});
      for(let i=0; i < URIs.length; ++i){
        zip.file(URIs[i].filename, URIs[i].uri, {base64: true});
      }
      zip.generateAsync({type:'base64'}).then(function (b64) {
        var link = document.createElement('a');
        link.download = 'mytimeline.zip';
        link.href = 'data:application/zip;base64,' + b64;
        link.click();
      });
    });
}
$(document).on('shiny:connected', function(){
  Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('download', downloadZIP);
});"

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dom-to-image/2.6.0/dom-to-image.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jszip/3.5.0/jszip.min.js"),
    tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/PapaParse/5.2.0/papaparse.min.js"),
    tags$script(HTML(js)),
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "
        .red_point  { border-color: red; border-width: 2px;   }
        .blue_point { border-color: blue; border-width: 2px;  }
        .green_point  { border-color: green; border-width: 2px;   }
        .purple_point { border-color: purple; border-width: 2px;  }
        "
      )
      )
      ),
  DT::dataTableOutput("tbl1"),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "typeof input.tbl1_rows_selected  !== 'undefined' && input.tbl1_rows_selected.length > 1",
    actionButton(class = "btn-success",
                 "button2",
                 "GENERATE TIMELINE")
  ),
  
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "input.button2 > 0",
    
    timevisOutput("appts"),
    
    actionButton("download", "Download timeline", class = "btn-success"),
    
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.download > 0",
    tableOutput("test")
    )
    
    
  )
 
      )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$tbl1 <- DT::renderDataTable({
    data
  },
  caption = 'Select desired options and scroll down to continue.',
  selection = 'multiple',
  class = "display nowrap compact",
  extensions = 'Scroller',
  options = list(
    dom = 'Bfrtip',
    paging = FALSE,
    columnDefs = list(list(visible = FALSE))
  ))
  
  
  observeEvent(input$button2, {
    row_data <- data[input$tbl1_rows_selected, ]
    
    
    
    output$appts <- renderTimevis(timevis(
      data = row_data,
      groups = groups,
      fit = TRUE,
      options = list(
        editable = TRUE,
        multiselect = TRUE,
        align = "center",
        stack = TRUE,
        start = todayAM,
        end = todayPM,
        showCurrentTime = FALSE,
        showMajorLabels = FALSE
      )
    ))
    file_list <- as.data.frame(row_data$file_name)
    
   
      })
  
  observeEvent(input$download, {
    filenames <- na.omit(data[input$tbl1_rows_selected, "file_name"])
    


    #levels(filenames) <- c(levels(filenames), "memo.txt")
    #test <- "memo.txt"
    #browser()
    #filenames <- append(filenames,test)
    # levels(filenames) <- c(levels(filenames), "memo.txt")
    
    
    
    output$test <- renderTable(filenames)
   
    
    files <- file.path(".", "www", filenames)
    URIs <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(i){
      URI <- dataURI(file = files[i])
      list(filename = filenames[i], uri = substr(URI, 14, nchar(URI)))
    })
    table <- fromJSON(toJSON(input$appts_data), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "download",
      list(table = table, URIs = URIs)
    )
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**EDIT w/answer(ish)**
After trying (and failing) like so many others to deal with the factors, I wisened up and set my original "items" dataframe to `stringAsFactors = FALSE`
this is by far the easiest solution. From there the following works:

```
items <- data.frame(
  category = c("Room", "IceBreaker", "Activity", "Break"),
  group = c(1, 2, 3, 4),
  className   = c ("red_point", "blue_point", "green_point", 
"purple_point"),
  content = c("Big Room", "Introductions", "Red Rover", "Lunch"),
  length = c(480, 60, 120, 90),
  file_name = c("Toolkit_placeholder.pdf", NA, "Placeholder.txt", 
"Toolkit_placeholder.pdf"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)



observeEvent(input$download, {
    
   filenames <- na.omit(data[input$tbl1_rows_selected, "file_name"])
    static_files <- "memo.txt"
    filenames <- append(filenames,static_files)
    
    output$test <- renderTable(filenames)

    files <- file.path(".", "www", filenames)
    URIs <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(i){
      URI <- dataURI(file = files[i])
      list(filename = filenames[i], uri = substr(URI, 14, nchar(URI)))
    })

    table <- fromJSON(toJSON(input$appts_data), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "download",
      list(table = table, URIs = URIs)
    )
  })
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to manipulate the factors, the simplest answer was to set stringsToFactors as FALSE.  I am using R version 3.6, in R 4.0 that is now the default behavior.

I have updated the original question to include the answer.

Comment: That is great! I still don't see downloadZIP from the session$sendCustomMessage().  Perhaps my RStudio needs to be updated as it is still version 1.1.453

Comment: Did you place a couple of generic files in your www directory that match the filenames?

Comment: Yes I did.  Where (or which folder) will the downloadZIP be downloaded to?

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
 observeEvent(input$download, {
    filenames <- na.omit(data[input$tbl1_rows_selected, "file_name"])
    ## added the next seven lines; no other modifications to your code.
    filez <- file.path(".", "www", filenames)
    fnamez <- lapply(seq_along(filez), function(i){
      list(filename = filenames[i])
    })
    f2namez <- list(fnamez,"memo.txt")
    filenamez <- unlist(f2namez)
    filenamez2 <- data.frame(filenamez)
    
    output$test <- renderTable(filenamez2)

    files <- file.path(".", "www", filenames)
    URIs <- lapply(seq_along(files), function(i){
      URI <- dataURI(file = files[i])
      list(filename = filenames[i], uri = substr(URI, 14, nchar(URI)))
    })
    table <- fromJSON(toJSON(input$appts_data), simplifyDataFrame = FALSE)
    session$sendCustomMessage(
      "download",
      list(table = table, URIs = URIs)
    )
  })
```

No other modification to the remaining part of your code. This gives the following output:

[image: output]

Comment: Unfortunately that gets me to the same place. It adds the level, but not the actual item.  Browse[1]> filenames
[1] Toolkit_placeholder.pdf Placeholder.txt        
Levels: Placeholder.txt Toolkit_placeholder.pdf memo.txt

Comment: Hmm, with that I don't get the same output as you. My filenamez and filenamez2 dataframes contain two entries that corespond to the factor levels of the items, and then memo.txt.   So i get 2,1,memo.txt.

Comment: Not sure why.  I get all the non-missing values from the highlighted rows in table1 and memo.txt. You can use either filenamez or filenamez2.  I get the same result. My R is version 4.0, perhaps that might be the reason.

Comment: Hmm, how are you adding the filepath to the memo.txt item? It looks like you have the filepath modifications happening before it ever gets added to the list

Comment: Hmm, same result. I'm using version 3.6.0. Guessing it could have something to do with 4.0 changing the stringsasfactors default. I'll mess with that.  I'm still confused how the new table will get passed as URI's to the download function.

Comment: I have just added it to the list to display at the bottom. Some more work is required to pass as URIs to the download function.